# How to make web application built with ReactJs and a Java Spring REST API communicate in a Docker container?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a web application built with ReactJs and a REST API built with Spring.
I am trying to use Docker to place them in the same Docker container. I am also using docker-compose.

This is my docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./reactApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.react
    ports:
      - "9091:80"


  api:
    build:
      context: ./restApi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.spring
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

After running `docker-compose up`, and going to localhost:9091, the React application works fine in the browser and so does the REST API, but requests to http://api:9090:/[endpoint] aren't met with a response.

I tried just running docker-compose expecting things to just work, but they do not.

I tried accessing the shell of the react app, and running a `curl http://api:9090/omm/api/all`, it is receiving the expected data from the api.

This is the hosts file of the web app:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.25.0.3      cdd82d84a640
```

and this is the hosts file of the api:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.25.0.2      10b987b37baa
```

To my knowledge the api service should be somewhere in these hosts files, specifically in the web app's hosts file, but it is not, despite them being defined in the docker-compose.yaml

What am I doing wrong, I am trying to learn Docker, this is also for a university project and the professors are not open to communication this time of the year.